# Do all columns selected within a CTE need to be the same data type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I've been learning how to use CTEs and I keep getting the error "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric".

```
WITH ITEM_CTE
AS
(
    SELECT ITEMNUMBER, PRODUCTNAME
    FROM [REPORTING].[ITEMVIEW]
),
 QTY_CTE
AS
(
    SELECT QTY, LOCATION
    FROM [REPORTING].[INVENTORYVIEW]
)
SELECT * FROM ITEM_CTE
UNION
SELECT * FROM QTY_CTE
```

All columns are of the nvarchar data type except the QTY column (numeric). Do all columns within CTEs have to be same data type?

Comment: The UNION-ed columns must have compatible data types. (cte or not, doesn't matter.)

Comment: The data types of the columns defined *within* the CTE's isn't relevant here, it's when you `UNION` that the data types are important.

Comment: Your code won't run AFAIK...beyond this, in general all columns in the same position in a union query must have the same type.  Some databases, such as MySQL, will invoke casting rules, but SQL Server is more unforgiving.

Comment: SQL Server will implicitly cast to numeric. You must have data in `ITEMNUMBER` column that fails when this casting happens as it is not numeric. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=19640c77d33f87b780db4908c8a72b43. You would need to cast `QTY` to a string datatype or use sql_variant type (not something I recommend) to have both in the same column

Comment: Think of `UNION` as putting two results sets under each other (or *concatenating* them), and then removing all duplicates: columns from the two sources should line up!  Use `UNION ALL` to skip the implicit `DISTINCT` operation. As for CTEs, think of them as an alternative syntax for subqueries: `select a.* from (select * from b) a` becomes `with a as (select * from b) select * from a`

Comment: As for this particular query, it looks like a job for a regular join (inner for only items on inventory, outer for all items)